# Datatype mismatch in then/else in teradata

Tags: sql, case, teradata

I am checking the contents of `y.cap_ts` and if there is a value (non null) then replace it with `current_date` or else leave it as null. but I get data type mismatch in then/else error.

Here cap_ts is date data type.

Can any one suggest any better work around?

```
SET  
cap_ts  = CASE WHEN y.cap_ts IS NULL AND y.rwrd > 50  
                THEN current_date  
                ELSE NULL END
```

I am currently working in teradata.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to a static date? DATE '1980-01-01' Can you share the table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `CURRENT_DATE` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)`. I know you said that `CAP_TS` is a `DATE` data type but your naming convention seems to indicate otherwise. Unlike Oracle, the `DATE` data type in Teradata does not include a time component. If it is actually defined as a `TIMESTAMP` then you need to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(n)`, where n is the precision of the time.

Comment: Ya I was playing with it and replaced date with timestamp and it worked.